# Escaped space does not work in hyperlink

Tags: notepad++

I've recently started using the Notepad++ "Clickable Link" feature (found under Settings/Preferences/Misc/"Clickable Link Settings"). It works great.

But, I cannot get it to work with files that have spaces in the names.

This works fine:

```
file://C:\MyFile.txt
```

However, if the file has a space in the name, the link does not work: it is highlighted with an underline, but clicking on it does nothing. No error, just nothing happens at all.

```
file://C:\My%20File.txt
```

Is there some different technique I can use for handling spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harrymc is correct that you need triple-slashes for links with the `%20` syntax to work.

Additionally, according to [this Notepad++ discussion at SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/fc18989c/?page=1&limit=25#72b2), spaces must be replaced with `%20`.

> To be complete about hyperlinks :
>
> •Begin with the string file:///
>
> •Change, in the absolute path of the file, all back-slashes (\) by regular slashes (/)
>
> •Any character in Space ! $ ' ; [ ] ^ `` { } ~, must be replaced with, respectively, %20 %21 %24 %27 %3B %5B %5D %5E %60 %7B %7D %7E
>
> •Any character > 0x7F must be replaced by its hexadecimal code %nn, between
> %80 and %ff

I don't see any other way to get embedded spaces to work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the syntax for file protocol is three slashes for local files and
two slashes for remote, as follows:

```
Local: file:///C:\My%20File.txt
Remote: file://server/path/file.ext
```